Question on W. Rudin RCA 2.13

Theorem 2.13 : Suppose $V_1\cdots V_n$ are open subsets of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, $K$ is compact, and$$ K\subset V_1\cup\cdots\cup V_n.$$ Then there exists functions $h_i\prec V_i$ such that $$\sum_{i\in[n]}h_i(x)=1,\;(x\in K)$$.

On the proof of the theorem 2.13, if I accept it, every other part is alright, but the first line bothering me. The statement is given as

By theorem 2.7, each $x\in K$ has a neighborhood $W_x$ with compact closure $\bar W_x\subset V_i$ for some i(depending on $x$).

while theorem 2.7 is given as

Theorem 2.7 : Suppose U is open in a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, $K\subset U$, and $K$ is compact. Then there is a n open set $V$ with compact closure such that $$ K\subset V\subset \bar V\subset U.$$

So, in my understanding, theorem 2.7 says that if there is a compact set $K$ in open set $U$, there will be a some other open set $V$ containing $K$ in $U$ while $V$'s closure is inside of $U$.
The statement given in proof of 2.13 says that if $\{V_i\}$ is open cover of compact set $K$, while $\{V_i\}_{i\in[n]}$ is finite sub cover, for each $x\in K$ there exists a neighborhood $W_x$ which is containing $x$ as element and it's closure is inside of $V_i$ for some $i$.
For me, I couldn't get how could we assure the existence of such $W_x$ by theorem 2.7? To say the statement is true with theorem 2.7, I think there must be the proof of the existence of the compact set $M$ s.t. $x\in M\subset V_i$ but I couldn't get how could it be done.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Use local compactness.

I'm sorry about just posting links to pictures. I've edit the text. Thank you for advice. @JoséCarlosSantos

In the statement of theorem 2.13, you have a finite number of open sets $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n$; it is not being claimed that they form a sub-cover of some larger cover.
Anyway, if $x\in K$, then, since $K\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^nV_i$, $x\in V_i$, for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. And therefore, since $\{x\}$ is compact and contained in $V_i$, then, by theorem 2.7, there is some open set $W_x$ such that $x\in W_x(\iff \{x\}\subset W_x)$, that $\overline{W_x}$ is compact, and that $\overline{W_x}\subset V_i$.
Having said this, I must add that theorem 2.7 doesn't have to be used here. The fact that your space is locally compact is enough.

Thank you!! Your comment was really helpful for me to understand the proof.

I'm glad I could help.
